# IDW(Inverse Distance Weighted) Interpolation in openlayers (Custom Color palette)

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

Can someone provide me with an example on how to set my own custom colors with setData() from https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/doc/doc-pages/ol.source.IDW.html on a IDW vector layer.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to overwrite the setData methode:

```
idwSource.setData = function(v, data, i) {
  // Convert value to RGB
  data[i] = getRed (v);
  data[i+1] = getGreen (v);
  data[i+2] = getBlue (v);
  data[i+3] = 255;
};
```

Comment: Spot on! :) Thanks

Comment: I've added a `getColor method` to make it more clear : `idwSource.getColor(value) { return [r,v,b,255] }`

Comment: @ViglinoJean-Marc so it is better to over write the getColor method, right?